# How to add more than one word to ignore in regex Pattern

Tags: regex

Any suggestion for the below pattern:

```
^FILE\s+(myapps.*[^build-]?(Ess\.xml)) [A-Z0-9:]*\d$
```

The above pattern will get me lines that start with "FILE" and contain "myapps" followed by any character but should not contain word 'build-' or 'someword' and ends with "Ess.xml".

I am able to construct the pattern but I am not able to add more than one word to ignore i.e "build_" and "someword"

Below are few samples:

1. FILE myapps/abc/dfe/asd123123/sad/abcdEss.xml ABCD123:234234:AAS234:1
2. FILE myapps/efgh/qwe/advd123123/qwreqar/bad/dsgEss.xml C03858:BC4E4A:1
3. FILE efgh/qwe/advd123123/bad/abcd.xlf C03858:BC4E4A:1  - invalid because doesnt start with 'myapps' after FILE
4. DIR  myapps/yry/hjkyi/qweq/tyu/somefile_taskmenu.xml EWEF123SSD:234WEEDWE234:AASJH234:1 - invalid because doesnt start with FILE
5. FILE myapps/efgh/qwe/advd123123/bad/build-dsgEss.xlf C03858:BC4E4A:1 - invalid because contains build- in the word build-dsgEss.xlf
6. FILE myapps/abc/dfe/someword/sad/abcdEss.xml ABCD123:234234:AAS234:1 - invalid because contains noship

Comment: You don't want `build-` or `someword` anywhere in the string, or just after `fusionapps`?

Comment: Just so you know, `[^build-]` does not mean "Not build-" it means "Not b || u || i || l || d || -"

Comment: Note that the notation `[^build-]?` is a character class that specifies 0 or 1 occurrences of any character other than `b`, `u`, `i`, `l`, `d` or `-`; this quite a bit different from 'does not include `build-`.  And doing negated words is tricky at best.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes i dont want the build- or someword anywhere in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is a bit misguided - you've used a character class incorrectly. This term:

```
[build-]
```

is a "character class", and means "any single character of those listed", which us not what you want.

A regex that meets your requirements (as a java String) is:

```
"^(?!.*build-)(?!.*someword)FILE\\s+fusionapps.*Ess\\.xml [A-Z0-9:]+:\\d$"
```

This regex uses two anchored negative look-aheads to assert that the character sequences do not appear anywhere in the input.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/QPemE9czV4) on rubular of your examples matching correctly

Comment: You should explain that.  And 'the regex' is a grandiose; are you sure it is the only possible regex to to the job?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler very good point (and a good word "grandiose"!). There must be lots of ways to do it. I've changed my wording a "A" regex.

Comment: @Bohemian yes i need to ignore the lines that has word build_ and someword not the characters b u i l d _  But the above regex that you have given doesnt work for me either gettting syntax error.

Comment: The "syntax error" would have been from you not escaping (ie doubling) the backslashes when coding the regex as a String. I've edited the answer to show the regex as a java String. You can copy paste it from there into your program.

Comment: @Bohemian the syntax error is because you are missing ) in the end. But then it didnt match the pettern. Here is the sample entries which should match and doesnt match.

Comment: @Bohemian i have updated the question with samples to explain my question better.

Comment: Your examples were excellent - I've updated the regex. Also see the link to a demo. It's often much easier and better to explain with examples rather than words. Let me know if there are still problems with the regex.

Comment: @Bohemian One small update on my requirement. Is there a way i can apply in the above Pattern saying consider line with 'ess' only for the files with .xml and not for .xlf file. Let me know if i am not clear. i can explain with an example.

Comment: The current regex has `Ess\.xml` in it. It should already do what you just asked. Can you edit your question to add an example?